# Activiti Rest - Calling multiple instances concurrently

Tags: workflow, activiti, business-process-management, workflow-activity, bpmn

I have defined some simple BPM flows (F1) and deployed in activiti-rest.war. For simplicity, I have take a simple start-end flow.

I have written a REST client to execute the flow (F1) in parallel threads (20) with its required parameters for 1000 http requests.

**Problem:** I can see the flows are running sequentially, one by one response for the 20 parallel threads. It took a time of around 60 secs to complete with 20 threads (even when increased to 50 threads) it is the same.

Activiti Version : 5.15 
What should be the problem here ?. Any help will be really useful.
activiti-rest/service/runtime/process-instances - Rest URL used to start the instance

Thanks,

Yoka

Answer (score 2):

At last i found the solution.

It could be of two reasons
1) Make sure task's "Exclusive" property is set to false. But it needs more analysis on how your process task will be running. Refer the below link for further information
http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#exclusiveJobs

2) If you run the activity rest application and the client process on a dual-core machine. It might be difficult to assess the response time.

Thanks,
Yoka

Comment: You may also want to have a look at the latest release 5.16 which introduces a fix for the optimistic locking issues that can result from parallel gateways.